# React admin unmet peer dependencies warning

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-admin

I want to remove dependencies installation warning during `yarn install` command, but I actually can't fix `ra-data-graphql-simple`, `react-admin`, and `ra-input-rich-text` packages unmet peer dependencies issues as displayed bellow:

```
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > ra-data-graphql-simple@3.13.2" has unmet peer dependency "ra-core@^3.9.0".
warning "ra-data-graphql-simple > graphql-ast-types-browser@1.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.11.7".
warning "ra-data-graphql-simple > ra-data-graphql@3.11.4" has unmet peer dependency "ra-core@^3.9.0".
warning " > ra-input-rich-text@3.5.5" has unmet peer dependency "ra-core@^3.0.0".
warning " > ra-input-rich-text@3.5.5" has unmet peer dependency "ra-ui-materialui@^3.0.0".
warning "react-admin > connected-react-router@6.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "history@^4.7.2".
```

I have already tried to install those mentioned package but it broke the application instead.

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webpack, in your webpack.config file add the stats property like below,

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  stats: { warnings:false }
}
```

They claim to have addressed this in Yarn 2.

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4064

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6672

Without upgrading yarn, you could try `--showMissing` `--verbose` flags as they suggest.